# What are the potential risks and consequences of storing Bolt Terminals Sealed Lead Acid AGM (VRLA) Rechargeable Battery in a 90-degree orientation?

Tags: batteries, position

I am interested in understanding the potential risks and consequences of storing the TLV12280 - 12V 28Ah, F3 Nut & Bolt Terminals Sealed Lead Acid AGM (VRLA) Rechargeable Battery in a 90-degree orientation. This battery is 6.54" (166 mm) long, 6.89" (175 mm) wide, and 4.92" (125 mm) high.

While the battery is designed to be spill-proof, there is a Quora comment that warns about the potential issues of storing a lead-acid battery upside down, including leaking sulfuric acid, exposing the bottom of the plates, and significantly reducing the battery's capacity [Source 2](http://batterylifesaver.com/2011/08/basic-orientation-of-lead-acid-batteries/), as you can see in the [Quora comment below, too.](https://www.quora.com/What-will-happen-to-a-battery-if-we-place-it-upside-down):

> Lead acid batteries are VERY orientation sensitive and will likely spill their sulphuric acid electrolyte if inverted. BTW Installation in some holder within a device IS SPECIFIC with regard to orientation.
> If you put them into the device in wrong orientation, your device will NOT function.
>
> It will leak Sulphuric acid all over the place, expose the bottom of the plates so the lead paste starts to fall off, and reduce it’s capacity significantly. YOU WILL KILL IT.

This comment does not specifically address sealed lead-acid batteries like the one I have. I would appreciate any information on the potential risks and consequences of storing this specific battery model in a 90-degree orientation.

The batteries model and information would be available below (this model is similar to our batteries):

[Link to the product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01E7GQD5S)

[image]

The orientation of this kind of placing batteries is shown below:

[image]

**Update 1:**
I have seen this comment and I guess it is ok to put them in 90 degree difference of upright  position ([comment link](https://www.quora.com/What-will-happen-to-a-battery-if-we-place-it-upside-down)):

> VRLA batteries can virtually be installed in any position. However, you should definitely try to avoid installing your VRLA battery upside down. Though VRLA batteries are technically sealed and spill proof, they might leak in the long-term if they are constantly charged and discharged while they are upside down. If you can’t possible install the VRLA battery upright, your best option would be to install it on its side.

Comment: It's so important in this situation that if the manufacturer's data doesn't give an indication that you speak with them and get stuff in writing. You can't rely (not one bit) on Amazon providing those details. Contact the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a **sealed** lead acid battery, those can be used in almost any orientation.

However, they could leak from the overpressure vents when abused.
Safest is upright.

If you find branded batteries with a datasheet instead of amazon no-names you will find a statement such as : "*Operation in any orientation (excluding continuous inverted use)*" ([source, Yuasa NPC24-12I](https://www.yuasa.it/batteries/industrial/npc-vrla-cyclic-use/npc24-12i-npc24-12i.html))